# Computing $\frac{\partial f \circ g}{\partial x_n}(g^{-1}(p))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, chain-rule

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^{q}$ for $q \geq 1$. Suppose $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p) \neq 0$ for some $p \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Define $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by

$g(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n, \ldots, x_i)$. That is $g$ swaps the $i$th and $n$th coordinates. $g$ is of class $C^{\infty}$. I need to show that

$$\frac{\partial(f \circ g)}{\partial x_n}(g^{-1}(p)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p) \neq 0.$$

However, when I do this computation I get

$$\frac{\partial(f \circ g)}{\partial x_n}(g^{-1}(p)) = (\nabla f \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n})(g^{-1}(p))$$

where $\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial x_n} = (0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$ where the $1$ is in the $i$th position. Thus I should get

$\frac{\partial(f \circ g)}{\partial x_n}(g^{-1}(p)) = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x_i}(g^{-1}(p))$, which is not what I wanted. Therefore I must be doing something wrong. I think it must be when I do the chain rule. Any insight as to where I went wrong and what the right process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems there ought to be a simple proof under weaker assumptions than belonging to $C^q. \qquad$

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the assumptions about $f \in C^{q}$ is necessary, probably just that $f$ has first order partials in each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured out what's wrong. The equation

$$\frac{\partial f\circ g}{\partial x_n} = (\nabla f \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}) $$
is not right. Rather we have

$$\frac{\partial f\circ g}{\partial x_n} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\circ g\right) \frac{\partial{g_j}}{\partial x_n} = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\circ g\right)$$
Plugging in $g^{-1}(p)$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Yup, this works much better.  $$ d(f \circ g)(q) = d_{g(q)} f \circ d_{q}g$$. Here $q = g^{-1}(p)$ and $d_{q}g = (0,...,1,...,0)$. (by this I mean yours)

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I think this does it.